# What ads are you seeing on this site?

Tags: discussion, sponsorship-and-advertising, new-users, low-rep-users

As someone who regularly advertises MMSE to many people, how MMSE looks when people visit it upon my recommendation, will affect my personal reputation.

I recently noticed that with only 141 rep on Cryptography.SE, I see a rather large and loud advertisement ***between*** a question's title and its body, which makes it very hard to miss:

[image]

If you're seeing ads on MMSE, what do they look like?